# regex match doesn't find last match right

Tags: regex, replace

I cannot find my problem in regex, at my last element **footer**, last match should be **footer** of this element, but it gives me last match **html**... any idea what i am doing wrong? Here is my regex code https://regex101.com/r/rJ6vV1/3

Comment: Share your code here please.

Comment: Regexes are bad for things like parsing HTML (or anything that nests). You should consider using an HTML parsing library. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: never ever use regex for html. why people keep using bad tools?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `<` or `>` inside the negated character class.

```
<(.+) data-edit="true" data-id="(.*)"(.*?)>([^<"]*)<\/(.+)>
                                              ^
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rJ6vV1/4)

`[^"]` matches all the characters except double quotes , so `<`, `\n` also got matched.

Always use a non-greedy regex like below.

```
<(.+?) data-edit="true" data-id="(.*?)"(.*?)>([^>"]*)<\/(.+?)>
```

Like others said, don't use regex to parse html files. Use it only if you know the consequences.